# Steam won't work

Tags: steam, pc

My computer was reformatted but the when I try to open Steam now it gives me this message

> Steam failed to load StartSteamEngine(0x1bf598) failed with error 1.  Unable to write to the current Steam application folder. Please move Steam to a folder where you have write priveleges"

I am anything but techy, so does anybody have an idiot's guide to what to do next? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you try reinstalling steam?

Comment: Where is the Steam folder located? Also, are you running it with administrator/root privileges?

Comment: This is stupidly simple but worth a try,just right click the steam.exe an chose "run as administrator"

Answer (score 5):

In recent versions of Windows, the 'Program Files' and 'Program Files (x86)' have restricted write access.

The most straightforward fix is to uninstall and reinstall Steam using the default installation settings.

This should write the Steam files in a "VirtualStore" folder than can be accessed as if it were actually in the 'Program Files' folder. It's probably more than you want to know, but you can see more details in the answers to [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/384107/why-cant-i-edit-a-program-files-file-on-windows-7).